# Why I can't create objects of my class in swift using AlamoFire and SwiftyJson?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a function that creates an object from json node in swift:

```
class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> SingleRequest? {
    var title: String
    if let titleOrNil = json["title"].string {
        title = titleOrNil
    } else {
        title = ""
    }
    let locationName = json["location"].string
    let discipline = json["discipline"].string



     let lat = json["location"]["coordinates"][1].doubleValue
    let lon = json["location"]["coordinates"][0].doubleValue
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    return SingleRequest(title: title, locationName: locationName!, discipline: discipline!, coordinate: coordinate)
}
```

now, using `alamofire` and `swiftyJson` I'm trying to fetch all data from my webservice and create `SingleRequest` objects. I do it as shown below:

```
func fetchRequests(radius: Double, lat: Double, lon: Double){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://mywebservice")
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success:


                if let jsonData = response.result.value {
                    for requestJSON in jsonData {
                        if let request = SingleRequest.fromJSON(requestJSON){
                           //do sth with a single request here
                           //e.g. print(request.discipline)
                        }
                    }
                }


            case .Failure(let error):
                print("SWITCH ERROR")
                print(error)
            }

    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

[image]

So my question is - how, using `alamoFire` and `SwiftyJson` I can create my custom `SingleRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value {
    for requestJSON in jsonData {
        if let request = SingleRequest.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){
            //do sth with a single request here
            //e.g. print(request.discipline)
        }
    }
}
```

`jsonData` is an `AnyObject` that you need to cast to `[[String: AnyObject]]`:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for requestJSON in jsonData {
        if let request = SingleRequest.fromJSON(requestJSON){
            //do sth with a single request here
            //e.g. print(request.discipline)
        }
    }
}
```

What the error is saying is that since `response.result.value` is an `AnyObject` by default, it is not iterable. That's why you need to cast it to an array (e.g. an array of dictionaries: `[[String: AnyObject]]`).

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice, but when I used your snipped of code I'm getting an error: http://i.imgur.com/5NSkum2.png is there any way of fixing that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically, you you need to create a `JSON` object from `requestJSON`, because your `fromJSON` expects a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I don't know what "type" response.result.value is, but if it can be cast to something that can be iterated then here's an example of that:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [(some type that can be iterated)] {
    // do something with jsonData ...
}
```